# How to fix "id=error-page" default on index.php in a WordPress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, alignment

I am creating a custom WordPress theme and I want to have multiple pages that I create myself. After creating a second page, the home page now displays in a strange center alignment with `id=error-page` in the body tag after I changed the other page's template to the new page I created. None of this should of had an affect on the index page.

I have tried copying my index.php into home.php, but the index page still loads with the weird center alignment and contains the same `id=error-page` in the body tag. The page displayed fine originally, but after adding a page template for a new page I was trying to create, the index has changed.

Here is the first few sections in my **index.php** to show my code should be correct:

```
    <?php get_footer(); >

    <!-- Background Video -->
    <div class="video">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
        <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
          <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/FFHPainVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    </div>

    <!-- Hero Video Text -->
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="w-100 text-black">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xl open"><i class="fa fa-play text-white" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          <h1 class="display-3">Family First Healthcare</h1>
          <h1 class="display-3">Pain Management</h1>
          <p class="lead mb-0">An Athens Heart Center & Specialty Clinics Affiliate</p>
          <button onclick="window.location.href = '#'; " type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 px-4">Get Started Here ></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I expect the page to be normal when I load it, but I get a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500. (index):1` error as well.

Here are the most recent server logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to >undefined function 
get_ssite_url() in /srv/htdocs/wp-content/themes/No
Phun/footer.php:18

Stack trace:
#0 /wordpress/core/5.2.3/wp-includes/template.php(722): require_once()
#1 /wordpress/core/5.2.3/wp-includes/template.php(671): 
load_template('/srv/htdocs/wp-...', true)
#2 /wordpress/core/5.2.3/wp-includes/general-template.php(76): locate_template(Array, true)
#3 /srv/htdocs/wp-content/themes/No Phun/index.php(218): get_footer()
#4 /wordpress/core/5.2.3/wp-includes/template-loader.php(78): include('/srv/htdocs/wp-...')
#5 /wordpress/core/5.2.3/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/wordpress/core...')
#6 /wordpress/core/5.2.3/index.php(17): require('/wordpress/core...')
#7 {main} thrown in /srv/htdocs/wp-content/themes/No Phun/footer.php on line 18

[05-Oct-2019 01:03:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /srv/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wp-clone-template/main.php on line 119
[05-Oct-2019 01:06:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /srv/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wp-clone-template/main.php on line 119
```

Comment: Errors of status code 500 get logged in the server error logs. Check those and post the error message here (if you're not able to quickly see the problem from it).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the server logs, it seems it was something simple. In **footer.php**, it seems I had `<?php get_ssite_url ?>` instead of `<php get_site_url() ?>`. Sorry to waste everyones time, but I appreciate the advice to look at the server logs. They are a pain to get too because sites hosted on WordPress don't allow FTP access.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean sites hosted on wordpress.com or what, but WordPress as a CMS has nothing to do with access to server logs. That's entirely up to your hosting provider.

Comment: My website is hosted with WordPress.

Comment: Two totally separate things. WordPress.com is a hosting provider; WordPress is a CMS that is distributed at WordPress.org.